# WordPress continually requests pages from itself

Tags: plugins, apache

in my Apache log files, I find (some informations have been obfuscated) :

```
aa.bb.cc.dd - - [31/May/2016:16:58:24 +0200] "GET /tag/tag1/ HTTP/1.0" 200 9947 "-" "WordPress/4.5.2; www.example.com"
aa.bb.cc.dd - - [31/May/2016:16:58:26 +0200] "GET /tag/tag2/ HTTP/1.0" 200 9948 "-" "WordPress/4.5.2; www.example.com"
aa.bb.cc.dd - - [31/May/2016:16:58:28 +0200] "GET /tag/tag3/ HTTP/1.0" 200 9670 "-" "WordPress/4.5.2; www.example.com"
aa.bb.cc.dd - - [31/May/2016:16:58:30 +0200] "GET /tag/tag4/ HTTP/1.0" 200 9898 "-" "WordPress/4.5.2; www.example.com"
aa.bb.cc.dd - - [31/May/2016:16:58:32 +0200] "GET /tag/tag5/ HTTP/1.0" 200 9754 "-" "WordPress/4.5.2; www.example.com"
```

where aa.bb.cc.dd is the IP address of the server itself.

I can have more than 100k requests from the server within a day.

Same URL are requested several times a day (approx each hour).

Do you have any clue why these requests are generated and if any optimization might or must be done ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Impossible to guess, that's certainly not a native WP behavior.

*If* the requests are indeed being made by WP's API you could hook into it and log what is happening to have more insight into the issue.

`pre_http_request` should be a fitting hook everything of the kind passes through, as far as I remember.

Comment: By intuition, i finally found that these requests are generated by a cache plugin. This plugin was configured to refresh the cache once an hour. I find your answer useful, because you provide a good entry point to investigate on these kind of issues.